# Select specific cell at runtime

Tags: vb.net, focus, cell, ultrawingrid

I have an `UltraWinGrid` and there is a test on a column to make sure the data entered does not already exists. If it exists, I show a `MessageBox` and I want the focus to be set on the cell again (to make sure the user enters something valid).

Right now, after the `MessageBox` appears, the selected cell by default is the next one. I tried this:

```
myUltraWinGrid.ActiveCell = e.Cell
```

I'm in the `BeforeCellUpdate` event so `e.Cell` refers to the cell I want to set the focus to..

Any ideas how I could do this ?

Comment: What was the result of trying? Did the next cell get selected anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try some of the [UltraGridActon](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.html) options available through `PerformAction`.

`PrevCellByTab` sounded like it might do what you want. It "Activates the previous visible cell relative to the ActiveCell and puts it into edit mode". If not, one of the other options may work.

```
ultraGrid1.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.PrevCellByTab)
```